# Amazon S3のstaticWebsite構築時にframeset>frameを取り除きたい

Tags: dns

Amazon S3のstaticWebsiteを構築したところ、自分がいれてCSSが効かない、
検証してみたら以下のように本来のソースを囲んでるようなっていました。
どのようにしたら解決できますか。

domainはgodaddyから取得しgodaddyにawsのnameserverを登録してました。
そしてそのドメインから接続は出来たもの、上記の状態に。

```html
<html>
<head>...</head>
<frameset row="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http:s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/作成したS3/index.html" frameborder="0">
    #document
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="jp">
        <head>...</head>
        <body>...</body>
      </html>
    </frame>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3には一切関係ありません。GoDaddy側の設定ではないでしょうか？

[ドメイン転送とマスキングの違いとは？](https://jp.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147)によると

> #### 転送のみ
>
> - 選択された目的地のURLに訪問者をリダイレクトします。
> - 目的地URLをブラウザのアドレスバーに保持します。
>
> #### 転送とマスキング
>
> - 選択された目的地のURLに訪問者をリダイレクトします。
> - ドメイン名をブラウザのアドレスバーに保持します。
> - 検索エンジン情報のためのメタタグの入力が可能です。

の違いがあり、**転送とマスキング**を選択されたのでしょうか。「ドメイン名をブラウザのアドレスバーに保持します」を実現するために`<frame>`を使っていると思われます。

**転送のみ**に切り替えれば`<frame>`は取り除かれますが、その場合、「目的地URLをブラウザのアドレスバーに保持します」とあるように、閲覧者のブラウザーのアドレスバーにはAWS S3のアドレス `http:s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/作成したS3/index.html` が表示されることになり、取得したドメインは表示されなくなります。

---

蛇足かもしれませんが、 ap-southeast-1 はシンガポールリージョンであり、東京リージョン（ap-northeast-1）とは異なります。